# Configure Windows such that new disks start out marked as offline?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-management

Is there a way to configure Windows in such a way that newly attached drives (i.e. drives that have never been attached before) will start by being marked as offline (as in `diskmgmt.msc`) instead of being online and getting drive letters assigned?

[image: Offline in the way the Disk Management snap-in means it]

**Note:** I would like them to be automatically *offline* and not "online but very briefly, *then* offline", i.e. something like [USBDLM](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) is *awesome*, but it's not what I am looking for.

Does such a setting exist or is this only possible with drives already known to the system?

Answer (score 1):

You can can enable/disable automount property using diskpart.

> Enables or disables the automount feature. When enabled (the default), Windows automatically mounts the file system for a new basic or dynamic volume when it is added to the system, and then assigns a drive letter to the volume.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart